# How to include several source files in Nsight Eclipse?

Tags: linux, eclipse, cuda, include, nsight

I have a project with many source files (examples: main.cu, a.cu, b.cu, c.cu, d.cu). Each with functions and kernel calls (**global** and **device**).

In a header (cpu.h) all the structures and definitions to be used in the host side.
Another header (gpu.h) all the structures and definitions to be used in the device side.

1. If I call kernel functions from **main.cu**, declared in **a.cu**. How do I **#include** those kernel functions declared in **a.cu** to use in **main.cu**, without doing the **not** recommended **#include "a.cu"**?
2. Do I create a header **a.h** with forward declaration of the kernel function in **a.cu**? Example:
   **extern void functionA(type);**

What about the CUDA kernel functions? Should I create a header file for each source file that is used from another source file?

- Where can I find some simple CUDA examples with multiple source files?

I mention Nsight Eclipse because I am having lots of trouble with it and multiple sources. 
I am using CUDA 5.5 Toolkits in a Ubuntu Linux and Mac OS environments. 
My main development environment is with 4 Tesla C1060 cards in the Ubuntu Linux machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **Separating kernels**. In a project, create two files (I refactored the default Runtime Project template and created device.cu and host.cu)

   device.cu:

   ```
   __device__ unsigned int bitreverse(unsigned int number) {
       number = ((0xf0f0f0f0 & number) >> 4) | ((0x0f0f0f0f & number) << 4);
       number = ((0xcccccccc & number) >> 2) | ((0x33333333 & number) << 2);
       number = ((0xaaaaaaaa & number) >> 1) | ((0x55555555 & number) << 1);
       return number;
   }

   __global__ void bitreverse(void *data) {
       unsigned int *idata = (unsigned int*) data;
       idata[threadIdx.x] = bitreverse(idata[threadIdx.x]);
   }
   ```

   host.cu:

   ```
   extern __global__ void bitreverse(void *data);

   ...

   bitreverse<<<1, WORK_SIZE, WORK_SIZE * sizeof(int)>>>(d);
   ```
2. **Separate Compilation**

   1. Right-click project, go to properties.
   2. Build/Settings.
   3. Setup build for SM 2.0 or newer.
   4. Select "Separate compilation" radio.

   device.cu:

   ```
   __device__ unsigned int bitreverse(unsigned int number) {
       number = ((0xf0f0f0f0 & number) >> 4) | ((0x0f0f0f0f & number) << 4);
       number = ((0xcccccccc & number) >> 2) | ((0x33333333 & number) << 2);
       number = ((0xaaaaaaaa & number) >> 1) | ((0x55555555 & number) << 1);
       return number;
   }
   ```

   host.cu:

   ```
   extern __device__ unsigned int bitreverse(unsigned int number);

   __global__ void bitreverse(void *data) {
       unsigned int *idata = (unsigned int*) data;
       idata[threadIdx.x] = bitreverse(idata[threadIdx.x]);
   }

   ...

   bitreverse<<<1, WORK_SIZE, WORK_SIZE * sizeof(int)>>>(d);
   ```
3. **Isolate CUDA code** One common pattern is to have CUDA code isolated in .cu files that have a host function wrapping kernel invocation. This way you can link object file produced from such .cu file to host code written in .cpp or .c files. Keep in mind that exported host code function should be qualified with `extern "C"` to be usable from .c files.

`extern` declarations can be put in .h file. Note that .h file with CUDA C syntax (`__global__` is CUDA C-specific) cannot be included in .cpp or .c.

**Adding files to projects**

Usually I just copy files to project folder, right-click the project and do "Refresh". Nsight will index them and include in the build.

**Excluding files from the build**

If you absolutely need to, you can copy device code to headers and include the headers (convention is to have .cuh extension for such header files, though .h works just the same). You can include .cu - the problem is that Nsight considers such files a source files and tries to compile them. You may exclude .cu file from the build by checking "Exclude resource from the build" checkbox in the top of any property page in the Build subtree in build properties.

**CUDA multi-file samples**

Pretty much any non-trivial sample is broken up into multiple files. Just create an Nsight project from, e.g., "Particles" sample.

Comment: I don't understand some parts. Why you have in device.cu two bitreverse kernel functions? I think one is your global kernel function and the other the device. Can they have the same name?

Comment: Oh, right :) That's bit untidy to have two functions with same name - I simply have them to show that both kernel (`__global__`) and device (`__device__`) functions can be in a different files. Note that `bitreverse` function name is overloaded with different argument list. You cannot override by CUDA declaration specifiers alone (e.g. you can't have `__global__` and `__device__` functions with the same name and arguments list).

Comment: SM 1.3 does not support separate compilation (referencing `__device__` functions from different source files). You may still use approach [1] (putting kernel to a separate source file) or [3] - to provide a host wrapper that sits in the same .cu as device code.

Comment: How do I deal with kernel functions like `template 
__global__ void MCMLKernel(SimState d_state, GPUThreadStates tstates)`? How do I `extern` call to it from a separate source?

Comment: Templated kernels should be in headers, same as other C++ templates.

Comment: I proceeded with the approach [1] described in your answer. The template kernel has calls to other `__device__` kernels which are called from the template like normal functions like RestoreThreadState(&d_state, &tstates, &photon, &rnd_x, &rnd_a, &is_active);... But the compiler thinks is a variable which cannot be initialized. Any ideas on how to solve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: @mrei, can you add sample function declaration and invocation? I am not sure I understand the issue. You can update your question (or start a new one and give a link in comment here) - there's better formatting support when editing question/answer.

Comment: I created a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170056/template-functions-calls-to-other-functions

Comment: would you be able to expand on approach [3] Isolated CUDA code, related to this answer? Using `extern "C"`. Probably is the way I should go with this code since I am having lots of trouble linking all the source files together.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/eugeneo/d66a2a3ea63afe9002e6 - it has no templates, but they have no bearing whatsoever.

Comment: Note that the issues you are seeing are not related to linking (and likely not CUDA-specific). Please provide code snippet in that other thread.