# Template function calls to other functions

Tags: c++, cuda, header, nsight, template-function

I understand the `template functions` usually are to be declared and defined in header files.

The problem I am having is that my `template function` makes calls to other functions. The prototypes of those other functions are in the same header file **before** the template function itself.

That portion of the code:

```
//header.h

template <int ignoreAdetection>
__global__ void MCMLKernel(SimState d_state, GPUThreadStates tstates)
{
  // photon structure stored in registers
  PhotonStructGPU photon;

  // random number seeds
  UINT64 rnd_x;
  UINT32 rnd_a;

  // Flag to indicate if this thread is active
  UINT32 is_active;

  // Restore the thread state from global memory.
  RestoreThreadState(&d_state, &tstates, &photon, &rnd_x, &rnd_a, &is_active);
...
...
}
```

The function `RestoreThreadState` is the first of several functions called from this template function. The others are called within a for loop.

I am not sure if this template function should or should not be in the header file. If should be in a header file, how do I call those other functions?

The errors I am getting from the compiler during the instantiation of MCMLKernel:

- error: explicit type is missing ("int" assumed)
- error: variable "RestoreThreadState" may not be initialized
- error: a value of type "SimState *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "int"
- error: expected a ")"
- warning: declaration is incompatible with previous "RestoreThreadState"

Additional details. All this functions are CUDA kernel functions. `MCMLKernel` is a `__global__` kernel and the rest of the functions it calls are `__device__` kernels. I am using Nsight Eclipse Edition and compute capability 1.3 GPUs (four Tesla C1060 cards).

Comment: Please create a simple complete code that reproduces the errors.  SO expects: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance"  You have not provided a SSCCE.org code.  Note that I'm not asking you to dump all your code into this question - just a simple reproducer.  Your premise is simple - a templated function or kernel calling other templated functions.  Create a simple reproducer of what you are doing.

Comment: @mrei - this works for me - https://gist.github.com/eugeneo/e681bf73020ddf0b5705

Comment: @RobertCrovella My question is more conceptual than anything else. How to create those calls? where to put the prototype of the template function? The kernel call to the template function is like this `if (hstate->sim->ignoreAdetection == 1)
    {
      MCMLKernel<1><<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(DeviceMem, tstates);
    }
    else
    {
      MCMLKernel<0><<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(DeviceMem, tstates);'

Comment: @Eugene I am going to try. Basically I have to move the function from the header then, right?

Comment: You can have kernel in another header (from compiler point of view, it's all the same). I updated the Gist.

Comment: @Eugene It works. About the updated version, can both the template and prototype of the the called function be in the same header? Or have to be in separate ones like the example? AND if I have a function which returns a value what precautions should I take?

Comment: Preprocessor merges all headers into the main source file. It is done before the compilation - hence, you can split them anyway you like. Please provide more complete source sample of the error you are seeing.

Comment: `nvcc -e your.cu` will show you preprocessed source file as it is fed to the compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Eugene provided the answer to this question.

I created the prototype of the called-to function like this

```
__device__ void RestoreThreadState(SimState *d_state, GPUThreadStates *tstates,
                               PhotonStructGPU *photon,
                               UINT64 *rnd_x, UINT32 *rnd_a,
                               UINT32 *is_active);
```

But, with an example given by Eugene it should be like this (NOT A PROTOTYPE! See other answer)

```
__device__ void RestoreThreadState(SimState *d_state, GPUThreadStates *tstates,
                               PhotonStructGPU *photon,
                               UINT64 *rnd_x, UINT32 *rnd_a,
                               UINT32 *is_active){}
```

Note the `{}` at the end.

Next in the code I call to functions which actually return values like this

```
__device__ int HitBoundary(PhotonStructGPU *photon);
```

Called from the same `MCMLKernel` template function. It is giving me a warning:

- warning: missing return statement at end of non-void function "HitBoundary"

UPDATE: In another source file **kernel.cu** I have the following declaration and definition (reason why I have multiple definition problems):

```
__device__ void RestoreThreadState(SimState *d_state, GPUThreadStates *tstates,
                                   PhotonStructGPU *photon,
                                   UINT64 *rnd_x, UINT32 *rnd_a,
                                   UINT32 *is_active)
{
  UINT32 tid = blockIdx.x * NUM_THREADS_PER_BLOCK + threadIdx.x;

  *rnd_x = d_state->x[tid];
  *rnd_a = d_state->a[tid];

  photon->x = tstates->photon_x[tid];
  photon->y = tstates->photon_y[tid];
  photon->z = tstates->photon_z[tid];
  photon->ux = tstates->photon_ux[tid];
  photon->uy = tstates->photon_uy[tid];
  photon->uz = tstates->photon_uz[tid];
  photon->w = tstates->photon_w[tid];
  photon->sleft = tstates->photon_sleft[tid];
  photon->layer = tstates->photon_layer[tid];

  *is_active = tstates->is_active[tid];
}
```

IN SUMMARY: I have four source files

1. **main.cu**
2. **kernel.cu**
3. **rng.cu**
4. **mem.cu**

Each source file, except **main.cu** has an associated header

1. **kernel.cuh**
2. **rng.cuh**
3. **mem.cuh**

where I want to forward-declare functions to use in **main.cu**.

Everything is fine until I get to the **template function** which calls functions from **kernel.cu** and **rng.cu**.

Comment: @Eugene the situation with the function which returns a value

Comment: @Eugene Can I ignore that since is a warning? While linking everything I have multiple definition errors even though all my headers have guards.

Comment: @Eugene Could it be that now, with the {} at the end I changed the functions into definitions? I have all those functions defined in another source file.

Comment: Yes, Eugene stated that.  The {} at the end creates a function *definition* not a prototype or forward declaration.  At the beginning of this "answer" you state that "I created the prototype like this... but it should be like this..."  That is not what Eugene is saying and I don't agree with that either.  If you want a prototype or forward-declaration, *don't* use the {}

Comment: @RobertCrovella I clarified the statement, thanks for point it out

Comment: Is it good and valid practice to declare and define functions in a header if they are not template functions?

Comment: Declaring functions in headers generally increases compilation time and may increase the resulting executable size. In some cases, though, it may be beneficial - e.g. compiler optimizations are generally more robust that link-time ones. Note that you may want to declare such functions `static` to avoid name collisions when linking the application.

Comment: @Eugene Thanks! I finally got it working properly. Basically, I declared and defined the `template function` and all the functions called by it on a header file to include in other source files where the `template function` is called from. Those other functions declared in the header needed to be `static` as you point it out. Where can I find information about `template functions`? The books I searched did not mention anything about the need to declare them in headers nor other considerations. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @mrei There is no need to specifically have templates in headers. The issue with templates is that they should be declared in the same "translation unit" where they are used. Headers are simply a way to split "translation unit" into several files for maintainability and reuse. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)

Answer (score 1):

`__device__ void RestoreThreadState(...);` is a forward declaration, meaning that a proper definition follows in the same translation unit (it may even be below function invocation).

`__device__ void RestoreThreadState(...) {}` is a definition of a no-op function.

`__device__ int HitBoundary(PhotonStructGPU *photon);` is a forward-declaration. Do you supply a definition?

**Update**

[Here's the Gist](https://gist.github.com/eugeneo/9663490c1b762c0c5b9f) based on code snippets you provided. I kept kernel, device function and types declaration in 3 separate headers. I can compile it (though obviously it can't be ran)

Comment: This is what I thought. I'm stuck with the problem in the other thread about multiple source files. All my functions are declared and **defined** in `kernel.cu`, for each function there I need to do a forward-declaration (prototype?) in a header `kernel.h` to be able to use these functions from `main.cu`. But I run into the template function problem which calls other functions.

Comment: I provided, in my answer below, with an update of the definition of the function, which is in another source file `kernel.cu`